# MySQL 8.0.26: Access Denied during GRANT PROXY as root, when connected via TCP/IP socket

Tags: mysql

#### Synopsis

When I am logged into MySQL using a TCP/IP connection, I am unable to perform the `GRANT PROXY` command, even though I am logged in as root. However, if I connect to MySQL using the UNIX socket, I am able to successfully run the `GRANT PROXY` command.

**Question**: Why am I getting "access denied" when I try to run `GRANT PROXY` as `root`, when connected using the TCP/IP socket?

#### Reproduction Steps

First, spin up a MySQL 8.0.26 container and get an interactive Bash shell inside it.

```
docker run --name testmysqldeleteme --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123 --detach mysql:8.0.26
docker exec -it testmysqldeleteme bash
```

Then in the interactive Bash shell:

```
mysql --user root --password=123 --host 127.0.0.1
```

In the MySQL shell:

```
# Enable the check_proxy_users feature
SET GLOBAL check_proxy_users = 1;

# Enable proxy users for the mysql_native_password authentication plugin;
SET GLOBAL mysql_native_password_proxy_users = 1;

# Enable the no-login plugin for MySQL
# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/no-login-pluggable-authentication.html
INSTALL PLUGIN mysql_no_login SONAME 'mysql_no_login.so';

# Create two users
CREATE USER trevor IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Trevor123';
CREATE USER trevor_proxy IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_no_login;

# Grant proxy privileges
GRANT PROXY ON trevor_proxy TO trevor;
```

**NOTE**: At this point, you should receive:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: Filed as bug over at the MySQL issue tracker: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=104621

Comment: sockets aren't tcpip, sockets work only on localhost. Also show the grants of the user?

Comment: @nbk This is reproducible from the ground up in a fresh MySQL 8.0.26 container. The GRANTS for `root` user are all at the default settings.

Comment: i still think that it is a typo see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/proxy-users.html  in the simple example, you create a user **with** a domain and not wothout them try this approach

Comment: @nbk I just tried using `username@localhost` and the same behavior occurs.

Comment: see if you get the list of the privilges of root, i guess P'ROXys iws missing

Comment: @nbk But root does have permission to `GRANT PROXY`. It just doesn't seem to have permission when connecting to the MySQL daemon via IP, but it does when connecting via UNIX socket.

Comment: i still need to see all there is  to kn ow about user root gramt and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `root` permissions on `mysql.proxies_priv`. By default, only `root@localhost` has the privilege to `GRANT PROXY` to other accounts. In order to grant `root` privileges to perform the `GRANT PROXY` command when connected via IP, you must first login using the UNIX socket and run the following command.

```
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO root@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This will create a record in the `mysql.proxies_priv` table. After this, the `root@<ip>` user will have access to perform additional `GRANT PROXY` operations.

See:

```sh
$ mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.26 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| root@%         |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> # Enable the check_proxy_users feature
mysql> SET GLOBAL check_proxy_users = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> # Enable proxy users for the mysql_native_password authentication plugin;
mysql> SET GLOBAL mysql_native_password_proxy_users = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> # Enable the no-login plugin for MySQL
mysql> # https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/no-login-pluggable-authentication.html
mysql> INSTALL PLUGIN mysql_no_login SONAME 'mysql_no_login.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> # Create two users
mysql> CREATE USER trevor IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Trevor123';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER trevor_proxy IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_no_login;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> # Grant proxy privileges
mysql> GRANT PROXY ON trevor_proxy TO trevor;
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1'

mysql> select * from mysql.proxies_priv\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Host: localhost
        User: root
Proxied_host: 
Proxied_user: 
  With_grant: 1
     Grantor: boot@
   Timestamp: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit;
Bye

$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 8.0.26 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> # Enable the check_proxy_users feature
mysql> SET GLOBAL check_proxy_users = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> # Enable proxy users for the mysql_native_password authentication plugin;
mysql> SET GLOBAL mysql_native_password_proxy_users = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> # Enable the no-login plugin for MySQL
mysql> # https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/no-login-pluggable-authentication.html
mysql> INSTALL PLUGIN mysql_no_login SONAME 'mysql_no_login.so';
ERROR 1125 (HY000): Function 'mysql_no_login' already exists

mysql> # Create two users
mysql> CREATE USER trevor IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Trevor123';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'trevor'@'%'

mysql> CREATE USER trevor_proxy IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_no_login;
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'trevor_proxy'@'%'

mysql> # Grant proxy privileges
mysql> GRANT PROXY ON trevor_proxy TO trevor;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for trevor;
+---------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for trevor@%                               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `trevor`@`%`                |
| GRANT PROXY ON 'trevor_proxy'@'%' TO 'trevor'@'%' |
+---------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mysql.proxies_priv\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Host: %
        User: trevor
Proxied_host: %
Proxied_user: trevor_proxy
  With_grant: 0
     Grantor: root@localhost
   Timestamp: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        Host: localhost
        User: root
Proxied_host: 
Proxied_user: 
  With_grant: 1
     Grantor: boot@
   Timestamp: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I appreciate your interest in helping to answer this question. However, I am not sure I understand what you're getting at. You've reproduced the problem, but I'm still unclear why this behavior is occurring. It doesn't seem intentionally designed this way, and the documentation for `GRANT PROXY` doesn't indicate any limitations over TCP/IP sockets, versus UNIX sockets.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan: You are connecting with the `root@127.0.0.1` or `root@%` user but in `mysql.proxies_priv` table only `root@localhost` has permissions for `PROXY`. You will also have `skip-name-resolve` variable set in your Docker container (my.cnf).